# additional PDFs in helm-bibtex

Tags: bibtex, helm-bibtex

I daily use helm-bibtex to manage my citations / bibliography and add in the file field the path to the PDF of the related article.
I've read it was possible to add supplementary files (additional PDFs) as follows:

```
@article{KEY,
author = {AUTHOR},
title = {{TITLE}},
journal = {Critical care (London, England)},
year = {2009},
volume = {13},
number = {3},
pages = {R98},
file = {file1.pdf; file2.pdf}
}
```

However, this does not work, i.e. when I try to open PDF, none of the file opens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

The issue is not in the lisp code itself but it requires all the PDFs to be in the same directory.
If they're not, the list of `bibtex-completion-library-path` should include all the paths.